# Windows 10 administrator account

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

Why does Windows 10 warn me that a program "can't be opened using the built-in administrator account" when I am logged in under a **different** (non-built-in) administrator account?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Not really.  I already knew how to allow the built-in admin account to perform the operations.  I was trying to figure out why Windows 10 was trying to use the that account when I was already logged-in as a "regular" administrator.